# Using a websocket client as a class in python

Tags: python, class, websocket

I'm trying access some data using websockets, but I cannot really get around the examples given in the websockets documentation.

I have this code (https://pypi.org/project/websocket_client/) and want to transform it into a class.

```
import websocket
import thread
import time

def on_message(ws, message):
    print message

def on_error(ws, error):
    print error

def on_close(ws):
    print "### closed ###"

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            ws.send("Hello %d" % i)
        time.sleep(1)
        ws.close()
        print "thread terminating..."
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org/",
                                on_message = on_message,
                                on_error = on_error,
                                on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open

    ws.run_forever()
```

The idea is to have this all websocket functionality in a class so that I can just create an object of that class.

I tried to start doing it but I cannot even get passed this:

```
class MySocket(object):
    def __init__(self):
        websocket.enableTrace(True)
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org:12300/foo",
                                    on_message = on_message,
                                    on_error = on_error,
                                    on_close = on_close)

    def on_message(ws, message):
        print message

    def on_error(ws, error):
        print error

    def on_close(ws):
        print "### closed ###"

    def on_open(ws):
    ws.send("Hello %d" % i)
```

The error starts right away in `on_message` saying that's an "unresolved reference".

Answer (score 31):

Package the call inside an anonymous `lambda` function to achieve a proper call with the correct `self`:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self, db, symbols):
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://the.server.com/api",
                    on_message = lambda ws,msg: self.on_message(ws, msg),
                    on_error   = lambda ws,msg: self.on_error(ws, msg),
                    on_close   = lambda ws:     self.on_close(ws),
                    on_open    = lambda ws:     self.on_open(ws))

    def on_message(self, ws, message):
            msg = json.loads(message)
            print(msg)
    ...
```

Comment: This seems like the correct way to solve the problem

Comment: It can be simpler without lambdas: `on_message=self.on_message, on_error=self.on_error, ...`

Comment: @gil9red without lambdas, you lose `self`. In other words, inside the `on_message`, `self` will not point to the instance of your object.

Comment: Much Thanks. save me hours.

Comment: I've tried both with lambda and self.on_message but I still get `on_open() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ws'`

Answer (score 8):

The `WebSocketApp` needs callable objects for its callbacks (both the ones you pass in the constructor, like `on_message`, and the one you're setting after the fact, `on_open`).

Plain functions are callable objects, so your non-OO version works fine, because you're passing the plain functions.

Bound methods are *also* callable objects. But your OO version isn't passing bound methods. A bound method is, as the name implies, bound to an object. You do this by using the `obj.method` notation. In your case, that's `self.on_message`:

```
self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org/",
                                 on_message = self.on_message,
                                 on_error = self.on_error,
                                 on_close = self.on_close)
self.ws.on_open = self.on_open
```

However, you've got another problem. While this will make your error go away, it won't make your code actually work. A normal method has to take `self` as its first argument:

```
def on_message(self, ws, message):
    print message
```

It's also worth noting that you're not really *using* the class for anything. If you never access anything off `self`, the class is just acting like a namespace. Not that this is always a bad thing, but it's usually a sign that you need to at least think through your design. Is there really any state that you need to maintain? If not, why do you want a class in the first place?

You may want to reread the [tutorial section on Classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) to understand about methods, `self`, etc.

Comment: Well, I can't get it to work like that. I try: ws = MySocket(); ws.run_forever(); and I get the error:  'MySocket' object has no attribute 'run_forever'. But perhaps you are right I should put this in a class.

Comment: @jbssm: Well, you define a class `MySocket` that doesn't have a `run_forever()` method. You create an instance of that class and try to call `run_forever()` on it. What do you _expect_ to happen? If you want your class to automatically delegate all unknown methods to `self.ws`, you can do that, but you need to write code for that.

Comment: Thank you. I'll stop using the class and try to use normal functions.

Answer (score 4):

```
import websocket

try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread
import time


class OnyxGenericClient:
    """
    Onyx Client Interface

    """

    def __init__(self, ):
        websocket.enableTrace(True)
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost:3000/",
                                         on_message=self.on_message,
                                         on_error=self.on_error,
                                         on_close=self.on_close)
        self.ws = ws
        self.ws.on_open = self.on_open
        self.ws.run_forever()

    # def initiate(self):

    def on_message(self, message):
        print(message)
        return message

    def on_error(self, error):
        return error

    def on_close(self):
        print("### closed ###")

    def run(self, *args):
        global driver
        driver = True
        while driver:
            try:
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Say something nice")
                p = input()
                self.ws.send(p)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                driver = False
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ws.close()
        print("thread terminating...")

    def on_open(self):
        thread.start_new_thread(self.run, ())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    onyx_client = OnyxGenericClient()
```

I wonder why everyone is still putting the `ws` parameter.

Read the error log.

File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websocket/_app.py", line 343, in _callback
    callback(*args)

```
    def _callback(self, callback, *args):
    if callback:
        try:
            if inspect.ismethod(callback):
                callback(*args)
            else:
                callback(self, *args)

        except Exception as e:
            _logging.error("error from callback {}: {}".format(callback, e))
            if _logging.isEnabledForDebug():
                _, _, tb = sys.exc_info()
                traceback.print_tb(tb)
```

Looking at our callbacks,  `on_open(self, ws)`

When the `try` block executes it checks if our callback is a method or a function. 
if it is a method it would execute the `callback(*args)` already our self from our `CustomClient` is already passed as an argument in (*args). Mind you it already has its own `self` in `def _callback(self, callback, *args)`.
Hence,  every callback that is an instance of your `CustomClient` should not have the ws argument.

Comment: Thanks man @vc74 . Can’t even remember when I answered this. Makes alot of sense though.

Answer (score 3):

Just updating the code written by other authors on this page, that worked for me.
The problem is that in the event callback functions definition like on_message we should not use ws as parameter. self takes care of it and in the body of these event handler functions we should use self.ws

```
class MySocket(object):
    def __init__(self):
        websocket.enableTrace(True)
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org:12300/foo",
                                on_message = self.on_message,
                                on_error = self.on_error,
                                on_close = self.on_close)

    
    def on_message(self, message):
        # if you want to send something use like this
        # self.ws.send()
        print message

    def on_error(self, error):
        print error

    def on_close(self):
        print "### closed ###"

    def on_open(self):
        self.ws.send("Hello Message")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add "self" to you class methods:

```
class MySocket(object):
    def __init__(self):
        websocket.enableTrace(True)
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org:12300/foo",
                                on_message = self.on_message,
                                on_error = self.on_error,
                                on_close = self.on_close)

    def on_message(self, ws, message):
        print message

    def on_error(self, ws, error):
        print error

    def on_close(self, ws):
        print "### closed ###"

    def on_open(self, ws):
        ws.send("Hello %d" % i)
```

Comment: I does not work like that. I try: ws = MySocket(); ws.run_forever(); and I get the error: 'MySocket' object has no attribute 'run_forever'.

Comment: ws is not a WebSocketApp object.  its a MySocket object.  You would need to add code in the object to start it or simply call the run_foreever on the attribute like:
ws.ws.run_forever()

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm just not understanding the principles behind this. I'll stop using the classes for now and just use normal functions.

Answer (score 1):

The Self makes those methods as Class methods , Got this one working as the on_error/message/close methods signature  will get satisfied if called by self as will refer to the class itself .

```
 class MySocket(object):
   def __init__(self,x):
     websocket.enableTrace(True)
     ## Only Keep the object Initialisation here  
     self.x=x
     self.ws=None

     # call This method from a Object and it will create and run the websocket 
    def ws_comm(self):
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(self.WS_URL,on_message = 
        self.on_message,on_error =self.on_error,on_close = self.on_close)
        self.ws.on_open = self.on_open
        self.ws.run_forever()

    def on_error(self,ws, error):
        print "onError", error

    def on_close(self,ws):
       print "onClosed"

    #Send some message on open 
    def on_open(self,ws):
       self.ws.send(json.dumps(register_msg))

    def on_message(self,ws, msg):
       self.ws.send(json.dumps(msg))


 user1=Userapp('x')
 user1.ws_comm()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like try this way:

```
class FooClient(object):
    def __init__(self):
        def on_message(ws, message):
            print message
            # use 'self' variable to access other resource
            # handle message from websocket server like this
            self.handler.handle(message)

        def on_error(ws, error):
            print error

        def on_close(ws):
            print "### closed ###"

        def on_open(ws):
            ws.send("Hello %d" % i)

        # assign to 'self.handler'
        self.handler = FooHandler()
        # maybe there are another module should be initiated
        # ...

        websocket.enableTrace(True)
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org:12300/foo",
                                         on_message = on_message,
                                         on_error = on_error,
                                         on_close = on_close)

    def run_forever(self):
        self.ws.run_forever()

    def close(self):
        """clean other resources"""
        pass
```

Using inner function in method `__init__(self)` could avoid the problem that the arguments number of `on_message(self, ws, message)` method not match with the number of `WebSocketApp` provides to its argument `on_message` (class method has one more argument `self`).

I have a `handler` above to handle the message, method `close(self)` to clean some resources if I have, `run_forever(self)` to run websocket.

Comment: please describe the solution you provided

Comment: @DineshGhule I added some describe, if have something wrong in it please comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

```
class MySocket(object):
    def __init__(self):
        websocket.enableTrace(True)
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org:12300/foo",
                                on_message = self.on_message,
                                on_error = self.on_error,
                                on_close = self.on_close)

    @staticmethod
    def on_message(ws, message):
        print message

    @staticmethod
    def on_error(ws, error):
        print error

    @staticmethod
    def on_close(ws):
        print "### closed ###"

    @staticmethod
    def on_open(ws):
        ws.send("Hello %d" % i)
```

But you don't have access to self