# How to implement websocket inside a class?

Tags: python, class, websocket

I'm trying to use websocket.WebSocketApp inside a class so I could later on use the data retrieved from the websocket:

```
import requests
from urlparse import (urlparse, parse_qs)
import json
import websocket

class NeuroStream:

    def __init__(self, sensor, token):
    self._sensor = sensor
    self.token = token
    self.buf = []
    return

    def stream(self):
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
            "wss://api.foofoo.com/api/v1/features/" + self._sensor
            + "/real-time/?all=true&access_token=" + self.token,
            on_message=self.on_message,
            on_error=self.on_error,
            on_close=self.on_close)
        self.ws.run_forever()

    def on_error(self, error):
        print(error)

    def on_close(self):
        print "connection lost"

    def on_message(self, message):
        message = json.loads(message)
        biomarkers = message[u'features']
        c1 = biomarkers[u'c1']
        self.buf.append(c1)
```

When I define the functions on_error, on_close and on_message outside the class's scope, replace the self with ws and omit the self from their calls, it works. But then I cannot use

```
self.buf.append(c1)
```

Which is key for later uses

Edit:
The code I'm running before the error, and also before the case that works:

```
from NeuroStream import *
ns = NeuroStream('a_sensor', 'a_token')
ns.stream()
```

The error I get is:

> 'No handlers could be found for logger "websocket"'

I saw a similar thread, but it didn't help:
[Using a websocket client as a class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980966/using-a-websocket-client-as-a-class-in-python)

Comment: can you show us what code you're running to get that error?

Comment: Shouldnt `d.stream()` be `ns.stream()` , Where is `d` coming from?

Comment: I'm sorry you're right, don't mind that

Answer (score 1):

I observed two issues.

1) `"wss://api.foofoo.com/api/v1/features/" + self.sensor` should be `"wss://api.foofoo.com/api/v1/features/" + self._sensor` since you have defined `self._sensor = sensor` during initialization.

2) Looks like you are trying to use client side feature of `websocket` library.
Try installing `websocket-client`  as below and then re-run the code.
`pip install websocket-client`

Code is working for me with above two changes.

```
Python 2.7.14 (default, Mar 22 2018, 14:43:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from aam import NeuroStream
>>> ns = NeuroStream('a_sensor', 'a_token')
>>> ns.stream()
>>>
```